# python facing problems writing for loop logic when I have multiple items in my list

Tags: python, list

My for loop working when I have only one item in my list. see the code below:

```
remove_month_year = ["apple","banana"]   
for remove_m_y in remove_month_year:
    if remove_m_y not in time_posted: #I want to exceute this line of code if "apple" and "banna" not found in time_posted
       ....my others code

#time_posted is list of string like time_posted = "he eat apple"
```

But when I added more then one item I am facing the problems. Let you explain:
Assume I have two item in my list ["apple","banana"] so when I running the for loop first it will check for "apple" if apple not found then it will run my others block of code which is okay. The problems occurs when it's **checking banana** and found apple and my others block code running where I added logic not to run code if found apple.

Comment: Please clarify what ```time_posted``` is.   (fwiw, your variable naming is certainly 'interesting')  Please also include the actual output of your code and the expected output.

Comment: My gut feeling is that you are overcomplicating things. Agree with @ewong, please clarify.

Comment: Have you tried this `if "apple" not in time_posted and "banana" not in time_posted:`?

Comment: Zero no because I   have multiple items in my actual list

Comment: `#time_posted is list of string like time_posted = "he eat apple" `. That is *not* a list of strings; it's a single string. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s iterating over the array with one variable at a time, so imo you could either add a Boolean value which is changed upon one being present, followed by a conditional after the loop to check that Boolean value, or a more efficient way would be

```
remove_month_year = ["apple","banana"]   
if(not any(remove_m_y in time_posted for remove_m_y in remove_month_year)):
       ....my others code

#time_posted is list of string like time_posted = "he eat apple"
```

Not sure if this exactly will work, but I think it should…

any returns true if any element is true, and false if all are, so this is probably perfect

Comment: Pwuurple not working

Comment: Sorry, assuming your issue was it returning positive constantly, I just fixed it so it should work and not do that, if not, please explain what happened

Comment: Thanks it's working. can you please explain your code so I can understand how it's working. specifically what any() function doing here?

Comment: I used “not any” just make a false Boolean from “any” operate as a true boolean and vice versa, next “any” can use several booleans and if one is true it will return true, so I used it to check the following statements, which I used a for loop inside of to test all of the elements of “remove_month_year” against the string provided. —— So in the end, if any of the elements in the list were in the string, it would return a true statement which would become false, so it would only run the following code if no elements were in the string